# Smallest possible value of the magnitude of $|z-w|$

Tags: complex-numbers

Suppose we have complex numbers $z$ and $w$ such that $|z+1+3i| = 1$ and $|w-7-8i| = 3.$ Minimize $|z-w|.$ (Note that here $|z|$ means the magnitude of $z,$ not the absolute value of $z.$)

I tried setting $z = a + bi$ and $w = c + di$ and than calculating the magnitude, which gave me $(a+1)^2 + (b+3)^2 = 1$ and $(c-7)^2 + (d-8)^2 = 3.$ However, when I started solving, it got really messy fast. Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: Shortest distance will be along common normal of the two circles traced out by the two given expressions; note that $z$ and $w$ denote points on those two circles so the points defining the shortest distance between the circles will be the $z$ and $w$ for which $|z-w|$ is minimum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this figure showing the two circles help?

[image]

Comment: How should I interpret this graph? Should I minimize the distance between the two circles or something?

Comment: Ummm.... yep....  Find points, one on each, that are closest.  Can you see why?

Comment: Ohhh, I get it. But how what are the equations of the circles?

Answer (score 1):

You have two circles on the argand plane.
As to how they are circles, here's an intuitive explanation:

> A circle is defined as the locus of all points which are at a constant distance from a fixed point.

So when we think in terms of complex numbers: the distance between two complex numbers can be given as $|z_1-z_2|$ where $z_1$ and $z_2$ are any two complex numbers in the argand plane. So when $|z_1-z_2|=\text{constant}$ you should be having a circle if $z_1$ is the variable point whose distance from $z_2$ is constant.

So now that we understand why the given expressions are circles, we can move to find the shortest distance.

Our expressions for circles are given as: $|z-(-1-3i)|=1$ and $|w-(7+8i)|=3$. One of them has a center at $(-1,-3)$ and radius $1$. The other has a center at $(7,8)$ and has radius $3$. (All points correspond to the Argand plane)
Now we are required to find the least distance between these two circles. Let's have a visual of the situation:

[image: Graph]
We can very easily find the distance between these two circles using the distance formula. Try (just by looking at the graph) to find two points (one on each circle) which will give us the least distance between the circles (Hint: The shortest distance will be along the green line)

Now when you have the distance between the centers of the circles, what distance must you subtract from that to get the least distance? Can you carry on from here?

---

Related question: Can you find the maximum distance between the two circles?